# Python multiple series multiplication simplified

Tags: python

Guys I have the following short version of my code.

```
ab10=10
ab11=78
ab12=68

bc10=91
bc11=73
bc12=54

df10=87
df11=81
df12=90

b1=ab10/df10
b2=ab11/df11
b3=ab12/df12

c1=bc10/df10
c2=bc11/df11
c3=bc12/df12

m1=bc10/ab10
m2=bc11/ab11
m3=bc12/ab12
```

Isthere shorter way to make such multiplications as  I have more and more such variables to calculate by years from 10-12 ?

I tried `for i in range (10,12)` but not working. In my case variables ab10, ab11 and so on I used other variables. Doing everything manually takes lots of time provided there are more years not limited to 10,11,12 at least 10 years. I will be happy to hear any way to simplify the process.

I would. appreciate any thoughts or codes shares to direct me and make my work efficient.

Comment: You can use `list` or `tuple` instead of independent variables.

Comment: can you please show some code how can I use tuple with calculations to see how it would be automated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary for this kind of problems:

```
my_dict = {'ab10': 10, 'ab11':78, 'df10':87}

b1 = my_dict.ab10 / my_dict.df10 or my_dict['ab10] / my_dict['df10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using numpy if the amount of numbers is very high, the numbers are saved as vectors to which you can perform operations:

```
import numpy as np    
ab1 = np.array([10,78,68])
bc1 = np.array([91,73,54])
df1 = np.array([87,81,90])

b = ab1/df1
c = bc1/df1
m = bc1/ab1
```